# How to show content from next.js DOM immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm under the impression that the whole point of using SSR in Next.js is to have instant DOM render while react and other scripts are bootstrapped. However, when I throttle my connection, the page is just blank/white until the JS completes loading.

Here you can see the network preview (while throttling) shows the simple `<div>LOADING</div>` in the preview pane:
[image]

But the browser sees nothing until scripts finish loading. It has the same behavior even if we render `_app.tsx` content (with router, lazy-loaded components etc). CURL to same address shows the desired HTML.

Here's the minimal `_document.tsx` that's used:

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  static getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    return { props: {} };
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body className="bg-gray-100">
          <span style={{color: 'black', display: 'block', visibility: 'visible !important'}}>LOADING</span>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Is something hiding the body's elements while scripts load? Am I not understanding how `_document` works?

Issue persists with all three fallbacks, too `true` `false` and `blocking`

Comment: Can you show us the code of the page you're trying to render?

Comment: It's fairly basic, just some layout components:
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  return { props: {} };
};

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout
      SidebarComponents={SidebarControls}
    >
      <FAQ />
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default Page;